# C# Generics: Explicit restate of inherited constraints in overriden methods could break polymorphism?

Tags: c#, generics

**Mark Michaelis** wrote in his book (**C# 4.0 Essentials**):

```
class EntityBase<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public virtual void Method<T>(T t)
      where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Entity<T> : EntityBase<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public override void Method<T>(T t)
        // Error: Constraints may not be
        // repeated on overriding members
    where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> However, overriding members need to
>   conform to the “interface” defined in
>   the base class method. Additional
>   constraints could break polymorphism,
>   so they are not allowed and the type
>   parameter constraints on the override
>   method are implied.

Could somebody kindly explain to me what it means to `break polymorphism`? And in this example how could polymorphism break?

Comment: he does provide an excellent anti-example of a generic type `<T>` with generic method `<T>`, though ;p

Comment: Yeah, his examples are like that. But he explains things in an excellent way. I love his book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His example is confusing in part because of the (incorrect, IMO) re-use of `T` for a generic method within a generic type. The two `T` are not the same! So; let's work with a non-generic type:

```
class EntityBase
{
    public virtual void Method<T>(T t)
      where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Entity : EntityBase
{
    public override void Method<T>(T t)
        // Error: Constraints may not be
        // repeated on overriding members
    where T : IComparable<T>, ISomethingElse
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here I added `ISomethingElse` - and clearly the 2nd method could try to use features of this second `T` - however, the caller might be:

```
EntityBase foo = GetEntity(); // is actually an Entity (sub-type) instance
foo.Method<SomeType>();
...
EntityBase GetEntity() { return new Entity(); }
```

the base implementation does not enforce `ISomethingElse`, so the compiler does not complain that it isn't implemented. So what does the overridden method do? Hence it can't exist.

However! If you do this at the type level instead, it *does* work, as *for the concrete object to exist* we know the constraint was enforced:

```
class EntityBase<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public virtual void Method(T t)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Entity<T> : EntityBase<T>
   where T : IComparable<T>, ISomethingElse
{
    public override void Method(T t)
    {
        // ... can use ISomethingElse features
    }
}
```

And a brief reminder - if you have a generic type with `<T>`, don't also use `<T>` in a generic method; something more specific like `TValue` etc...

Comment: @Marc the questions are archived and for beginners like my self could you complete this (EntityBase foo = ...). Then I will accept your answer. Over all: good explanation.

Comment: @Marc lol ... marc I got it at the first place, I meant to make it CLEARER for beginners. Anyway, thanks for having the time answering my question. BTY: there is nothing called MethodX it's Method. ;-)

Comment: @Idrees - re  `MethodX` it was when I answered: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6242823/1

Comment: @Marc You are correct, my bad. But you should have guessed because it's an overridden method, it cannot have different name. :-)

Comment: @Idrees - sure, it was just copy/paste is what I am saying.

Answer (score 2):

If you were able to add additional constraints to the overridden method, it would break polymorphism.

Specifically, code that calls the base method with a parameter that doesn't meet your new constraint would break.

For example:

```
class Base {
    public virtual void M<T>() where T : Control { ... }
}

class Derived: Base {
    public override void M<T>() where T : Button { ... }
}


Base b = new Derived();
b.M<TextBox>();    //That's not a Button!
```

Comment: Did not get it. You are too brief.